# Using the Mean Value Theorem to derive Arc Length?

Tags: calculus, arc-length

The mean value theorem is used to derive the arc length formula and have questions on the value of $x_i^*$, which is  the argument to a function $f$ where equals the mean value.

Deriving Arc Length:
$$S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ||\vec P_n - \vec P_{n-1}||_2$$

where $P_i$ are points along the arc.

$$
||\vec P_n - \vec P_{n-1}||_2 = \sqrt{(x_i - x_{i-1})^2 +  (y_i - y_{i-1})^2}
$$

Mean Value Theorem applied:
$$
\frac {f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})}{x_i - x_{i-1}} = f'(x_i^*)
$$
where $x_i^* \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$.  $f'(x_i^*)$ is the mean value of $\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f'(x)$.

Substitute back in:
$$
f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1}) = f'(x_i^*)(x_i - x_{i-1})
$$
$$
\Delta y_i = f'(x_i^*) \Delta x
$$
$$ ||\vec P_n - \vec P_{n-1}||_2 = \sqrt{\Delta x^2+f'(x_i^*)^2\Delta x^2 } = \sqrt{1 + f'(x_i^*)^2}\Delta x
$$

By definition of the definite integral:
$$
S = \int_a^b{\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2} dx} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{1 + f'(x_i^*)^2}\Delta x
$$

**Question** why is the mean value theorem required?  Is it to find an mean for the derivative, but why?

**Question** how is the definition of the definite integral applied taking $x_i^*$ in account?  Do we just use the definition that $x_i^* \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$, even though it may be a specific value, and then the equality holds?

Appreciate your guidance